# WPF - Send Keys Redux

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, wpf-controls, keyboard-shortcuts

So, I'm using a third-part wpf grid control that is hard-coded to only accept certain keystrokes to perform short-cut reactions and one of those is Shift-Tab.
However, my user-base  is used to hitting up arrow and down arrow and telling them 'no' isn't an option right now. So my only option I think is to intercept the preview key down and send a different key stroke combination.

Now, I am using the following code that I found on here to send a Tab when the user presses the Down arrow:

```
if (e.Key == Key.Down)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    KeyEventArgs eInsertBack = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, Key.Tab);
    eInsertBack.RoutedEvent = UIElement.KeyDownEvent;
    InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(eInsertBack);
}
```

However, this method is limited in that you don't seem to be able to simulate a press of the Shift Button?  WPF seems to look at the Keyboard.Modifiers to be able to 'read' a Shift or Ctrl, but there doesn't seem to be any facility to Set the Keyboard.Modifiers programatically.  Any help out there?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{Tab}");
```

In WPF Application, SendKeys.Send not working, But [SendWait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait.aspx) is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Create a MockKeyboardDevice like this (kudos to Jared Parsons):

https://github.com/VsVim/VsVim/blob/master/Src/VimTestUtils/Mock/MockKeyboardDevice.cs

Usage:

```
var modKey = ModifierKeys.Shift;
var device = new MockKeyboardDevice(InputManager.Current)
    {
        ModifierKeysImpl = modKey
    };
var keyEventArgs = device.CreateKeyEventArgs(Key.Tab, modKey);
...
```

A usage example:

https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/blob/master/Test/VimWpfTest/VimKeyProcessorTest.cs

Answer (score 0):

I simulate what you say fine using the following is this not what you mean?

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();


    Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Window1_Loaded);
}

void Window1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser1_PreviewKeyDown(this, new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 1, Key.LeftShift));
    WebBrowser1_PreviewKeyDown(this, new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 1, Key.Tab));
}

private void WebBrowser1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Key);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
LeftShift
Tab
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is it. What I'm looking for is a key-stroke combination of Shift-Tab at the same time.

Comment: hmm I see.  It is weird because using Key.LeftShift | Key.Tab results in a CtrlLeft for some weird but probably good reason.  I will have a little more investigation when I can

Comment: @REA_ANDREW: You see this happening because `Keys` are not flags that can be combined, it's an enumeration where `Key.LeftShift = 116` and `Key.Tab = 3`. The result is 119 which maps to `Key.RightCtrl = 119` (Press F12 in Visual Studio when the cursor is on `Key` to open the definition).